# Using Array Method inside ASYNC/AWAIT between API calls in Javascript

Tags: javascript, reactjs, promise, fetch

I want to make my code more readable, using async/await instead of using fetch().

**My code needs to do the following :**

1. Fetch posts from API
2. Select the random post (using find() array method)
3. Make another API call based on the selected random post data.

**The way I did it using fetch()**

```
componentDidMount() {
    const postsURL = 'https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts';
    fetch(postsURL)
        .then(res => res.json())
        .then(posts => {
            const randomNumber = Math.floor(Math.random() * 100);
            const randomPost = posts.find(post => post.id === randomNumber);
            fetch(
                `https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/users/${
                    randomPost.userId
                }`
            ).then(res => {
                res.json().then(user => {
                    this.setState(() => {
                        return {
                            posts: posts,
                            showingPost: randomPost,
                            showingUser: user
                        };
                    });
                });
            });
        })
        .catch(err => console.log(err));
}
```

**Now I'm trying to convert this code altogether into one async function getData()**

```
async getData() {

    // get posts
    const getPostsResponse = await fetch(
        'https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts'
    );
    const posts = await getPostsResponse.json();

    // get showingPost
    const randomPost = posts.find(
        post => post.id === Math.floor(Math.random() * 100)
    );

    //get user
    const getUserResponse = await fetch(
        `https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/users/${randomPost.userId}`
    );
    const user = await getUserResponse.json();
    // return/setState
    return this.setState(() => {
        return {
            posts: posts,
            showingPost: randomPost,
            showingUser: user
        };
    });
}

componentDidMount() {
    this.getData();
}
```

The problem is - `randomPost` variable in this async function sometimes returns undefined. It has to be set before moving to the next API call.

**How do I properly use find(), or any other method inside async/await function between 2 API calls? Thanks!**

Comment: Is this not working?  What is your question?

Comment: @zero298 just edited

Comment: `posts.find()` is not asynchronous, you shouldn't use `await`.

Comment: The problem is that sometimes the callback function in your `posts.find()` call will never match any of the posts, so you get `undefined`.

Comment: It has nothing to do with changing the coding style, you should have the same problem with the original code.

Comment: @Barmar Still - same error **x
Unhandled Rejection (TypeError): Cannot read property 'userId' of undefined**

Comment: @getMaxed There's another difference. You're calculating a different random number each time through the `find()` loop, but you're only calculating it once in the original code.

Comment: @Barmar nope, using fetch it always mathes

Comment: Does the `posts` API always return an array containing IDs with every number from 0 to 100?

Comment: @Barmar yes, it does. I actually calculated random number outside of find() and  now it works. Thanks

Comment: Incidentally, the first version (without async/await) is missing a `return` statement. The second `fetch(...)` should say `return fetch(...)`. The way you've written it, if that second fetch fails, the `.catch` part at the end still won't run, because it's defined on a function whose handler has returned `undefined`. (A function with no explicit `return` statement returns `undefined`, and the promise returned by the `then` method resolves to the value returned by the handler passed to `then`.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You change the way you're calling `find()`. In the code that uses `async/await`, you're calculating a different random number to test each array element against, but in the original code you just calculate `randomNumber` once. The chance of finding a match in the second way is very low.

So do the same thing in the new code.

```
async getData() {

    // get posts
    const getPostsResponse = await fetch(
        'https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts'
    );
    const posts = await getPostsResponse.json();

    // get showingPost
    const randomNumber = Math.floor(Math.random() * 100);
    const randomPost = await posts.find(
        post => post.id === randomNumber
    );
```

A simpler way to pick a random element of an array is:

```
const randomPost = posts[Math.floor(Math.random() * posts.length)];
```